# Maxwell equation with complex permeability

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The EM wave in the whole space is described by the electric field $\mathcal E$ and the magnetic field $\mathcal H$ satisfying the Maxwell equations
$$\begin{cases} \operatorname{curl} \mathcal E + \mu \frac{\partial \mathcal H}{\partial t} = 0,\\ 
\operatorname{curl} \mathcal H - \varepsilon \frac{\partial \mathcal E}{\partial t} = \sigma \mathcal E.
\end{cases}
$$
where $\varepsilon, \mu$ are the permitivity and permeability of the medium, respectively. Is there any medium where the permittivity and the permeability contains imaginary parts?

Comment: See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#Complex_permittivity) and [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)#Complex_permeability)

Comment: Don't forget the [Kramers-Kronig-relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers–Kronig_relations). I guess iron is a material, what you are looking for